# Coletar Rota realizada GPS - Maps

Tags: php, javascript, apache-cordova, google-maps, maps

Galera, é o seguinte, estou querendo fazer um aplicativo que a exibirá para o usuário a rota que ele fez, a distância do trajeto percorrido e a velocidade média...

A minha dúvida é qual a melhor forma que eu poderia fazer isso? Estive observando hoje tem vários aplicativos no mercado que faz isso, por exemplo, a pessoa vai correr e no final mostra todos esses dados, a principio é isso que eu preciso...

O problema é por onde eu começo? Estarei utilizando o Cordova para desenvolvimento, usando o recurso de Geolocation eu tenho os dados do GPS, mas como iria fazer salvar o trajeto que a pessoa fez? E os demais dados?

Tentei procurar algo no google mas o problema que não sei nem por onde começar.... Hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

Para um aplicativo que utiliza rotas, a API do google é essencial. Para as outras funcionalidades aqui vão algumas ideias:

- Se o sistema ira mostrar para o usuário a velocidade média, você
  poderia fazer uma função que a cada X tempo pegasse a velocidade em que
  o usuário está e no fim executar uma média simples.
- Para salvar o trajeto você pode salvar no banco a Latitude e Longitude do ponto inicial e do ponto final.
- Para calcular a distancia dos pontos, você pode realizar a formula matematica de Haversine, que serve para calcular a distancia de dois pontos em uma esfera a partir da longitude e latitude. [Aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine)

Antes de pensar nas funções de uma estudada na API do Google que pode ser bem complexa, sem falar nos preços $$. Alem disso vale a pena dar uma olhada nos serviços de broadcasting, afinal a aplicação fará atualizações em tempo real.

Recomendações:

- Chaves para a api do google: [Maplink](http://maplink.global/pt/)
- Serviço para aplicações em tempo real: [Pusher](https://pusher.com/)

Abraços...

Comment: Opá, tudo bem Drealler? Obrigado pelo norte! Estava pesquisando e encontrei algo do Google Api Matrix que faz uns lances desses que preciso, porém eu preciso traçar no mapa a rota que o cara fez, exemplo, o cara vai sair do ponto A, ele vai andar e depois irá voltar para o ponto A novamente, o trajeto que ele fez, os lugares que ele passou, eu preciso exibir. Eu estive observando que poderia salvar a Lat/Lng em X tempo porém não consegui entender ainda essa api do Google Matrix, estou dando uma olhada, mas de ante-mão obrigado pela resposta.